# I want to check session data before an AJAX call in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax

In my shopping cart I want to check user session data before an ajax call.

If the user is not logged in I want them to redirected to login route. I have created a middleware called verifyLogin to check these login sessions for each time and it really works when not using an ajax. How can I add this middleware to my ajax function ?

Or please give me an another solution for this.

### VerifyLogin Middleware

```
const verifyLogin = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session.loggedIn) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

### Ajax function

```
function addToCart(proId) {
    $.ajax({
        
        url: '/add-to-cart/' + proId,
        method: 'get',
        success: (response) => {
            if (response.status) {
                let count = $('#cart-count').html()
                count = parseInt(count) + 1
                $("#cart-count").html(count)

            }
        }
    })
}
```

### Add to cart route of JS file

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', (req, res) => {
  userHelpers.addToCart(req.params.id, req.session.user._id).then(() => {
    res.json({ status: true })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the specified for session cookie-parameter by `document.cookie` is it set -- you are loggedin, else -- you are not logged in. Or, you can add extra cookie parameter that indicate if you successfully logged in. And this check you need to put before ajax call. Middleware layer will be working every time for any request to your server. But you need make check only if user trying to add something to cart, for example.

Comment: could you please explain it bit more detaily ?

Comment: Try to check value of `document.cookie` after and before auth. If you saw the difference - your authorization mechanism set the session only when user was loggedin. The difference will help you to indicate user is loggedin or not. So, you can check `document.cookie` value before you call ajax function.

Comment: If you does not see the difference, modify your auth. by adding extra cookie value. Existence of this value in cookie will help you to determine the user was be loggedin.

Comment: Or create extra endpoint for other ajax request that helping you to determine that user is loggedin. Make this request before and if response containing for example `True` then move forward, else make redirect to login-page.

Comment: I'm new to this topic. It would be easy for me if you write the code here